# kamailio fails to start because of invalid database credentials

Tags: mysql, freeswitch, kamailio

I'm trying to try my hand out with Kamailio and Freeswitch.
I'm following the article listed here:

http://nil.uniza.sk/sip/kamailio-33-and-freeswitch-122-interconnection-voicemail-and-conference-services-debian-squeeze-60-64bit-tutorial

After adding the #!define statements, the article says to try to restart kamailio.  When I do that, it fails with the error:

```
driver error:  Access denied for user 'kamailio'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm not sure which configuration file would contain the name of the default user that's used to log in to mysql.  I did make the recommended changes to kamctlrc where you define the dbhost, dbname and the read write user etc.  But none of those settings made reference to this user "kamailio".  Not sure where to check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon closer examination, I found that not only do I have an `/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg` file but `/etc/kamailio/kamailio-advanced.cfg.`

I made the changes the article suggested for kamailio.cfg in kamailio-advanced.cfg instead... and all is well.  I was able to start the service again.  I'm not sure if the database will work but at least I'm one step closer and now authentication is working.